# Flicker with StageVideo on Android tablet?

Tags: android, actionscript-3, apache-flex, mobile, flash-builder

I have a stageVideo class that I use it play a video on a tablet but every time I play a video the tablet screen flickers a few times (goes black then comes out of it about four or so times) I am wondering what could be causing this. It does this while I switch to the view with the video playing. The url of the video is passed to the video mxml view. I am using flex 4.6 and Android tablet (EEE transformer prime).

```
package ios 
{     
import flash.display.Sprite; 
import flash.display.StageAlign; 
import flash.display.StageQuality; 
import flash.display.StageScaleMode; 
import flash.events.Event; 
import flash.events.NetStatusEvent; 
import flash.events.StageVideoAvailabilityEvent; 
import flash.events.StageVideoEvent; 
import flash.geom.Rectangle; 
import flash.media.StageVideo; 
import flash.media.StageVideoAvailability; 
import flash.media.Video; 
import flash.net.NetConnection; 
import flash.net.NetStream; 


[Bindable] 
public class iOSStageVideo extends Sprite 
{ 
    private var videoPath:String; 
    private var videoWidth:Number; 
    private var videoHeight:Number; 
    private var _sv:StageVideo; 
    private var _vd:Video; 
    private var _obj:Object; 
    private var _ns:NetStream; 

    public function iOSStageVideo( path:String , w:Number , h:Number ):void
    { 
        videoPath = path; 
        videoWidth = w; 
        videoHeight = h; 
        addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAddedToStage); 
    } 

    //stage is ready 
    private function onAddedToStage(e:Event):void
    { 
        stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE; 
        stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT; 

        var nc:NetConnection = new NetConnection(); 
        nc.connect(null); 

        _ns =  new NetStream(nc); 
        _obj = new Object(); 

        _ns.client = _obj; _ns.bufferTime = 2; 
        _ns.client = _obj; 

        _obj.onMetaData = MetaData; 

        _sv = stage.stageVideos[0]; 
        _sv.viewPort = new Rectangle(0, 42, videoWidth , videoHeight ); 
        _sv.attachNetStream(_ns); 

        playVideo(); 
    } 


    //video is ready, play it 
    //public, can be called externally 
    public function playVideo():void{ 
        _ns.play( videoPath ); 
        _ns.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, videoStatus); 
    } 



    //required metadata for stagevideo, even if not used 
    private function MetaData(info:Object):void{ } 

    //get video status 
    private function videoStatus(e:NetStatusEvent):void{ 

        switch(e.info.code){ 
            case "NetStream.Play.StreamNotFound": 
                //do something 
                break; 
            case "NetStream.Play.Start": 
                //do something 
                break 
            case "NetStream.Play.Stop": 
                //do something
                trace('the video has ended');
                stopVideo();
                break; 
            case "NetStream.Buffer.Empty": 
                //do something 
                break; 
            case "NetStream.Buffer.Full": 
                //do something 

                break; 
            case "NetStream.Buffer.Flush": 
                //do something 
                break; 
            case "NetStream.Play.Complete":
                //do something 
                break;
        } 
    } 

    //stop and clear the video 
    //public, can be called externally 
    public function stopVideo():void{  
        trace("StopVideo is ran.");
        _ns.close();
        _ns.dispose(); 
        dispatchEvent( new Event('videoDone', true ) ); 

    } 

    public function stopVideoBack():void {
        _ns.close();
        _ns.dispose(); 
    }
}
```

}

Here is my code for the view that plays the video when the video is completed

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" title="" backgroundAlpha="0" creationComplete="init(event)" addedToStage="onAddedToStage(event)"  >

<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[

        import ios.iOSStageVideo;
        import mx.core.UIComponent;
        import mx.events.FlexEvent;



        protected var path:String = new String(""); 
        protected var backPage:String = new String("");
        protected var vid:iOSStageVideo = new iOSStageVideo( path , 1280 , 720 );
        private var arr:Array;
        //protected var vid:iOSStageVideo; 
        protected var container:UIComponent = new UIComponent(); 

        protected function init(event:FlexEvent):void
        {
            // Sets up the back button to back to the right slide
            arr =  data as Array;
            trace(data);
            path = String(arr[0]);
            backPage = String(arr[1]) 

            //creates the video
            vid = new iOSStageVideo( path , 1280 , 720 );
            loadVideo();

            //takes out the trash when the back button is hit so the stage video is ready when the new view is loaded
            stage.addEventListener("keyDown", handleButtons, false,1);
            stage.addEventListener("keyUp", handleButtons, false, 1);
        }

        override public function createReturnObject():Object {
            var returnedObject:Object = new Object();
            returnedObject.myValue = arr[2];
            trace("arr[2] ->" + arr[2])
            return returnedObject;
        }


        protected function loadVideo():void
        {
            //loades the video
            vid.addEventListener('videoDone' , videoStop); 
            container.width = stage.stageWidth; 
            container.height = stage.stageHeight; 

            addElement( container ); 
            container.addChild( vid ); 

        }

        protected function playVideo(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            vid.playVideo();
        }

        private function videoStop(e:Event):void {
                //removes container
                container.removeChild( vid ); 
                removeElement( container ); 
                navigator.popView();
        }

        private function removeEverything():void {
            vid.stopVideoBack();
            try
            {
                container.removeChild( vid ); 
                removeElement( container );
            } 
            catch(error:Error) 
            {
                trace("error with container");
            }
        }

        protected function onAddedToStage(event:Event):void
        {               
            if (stage.autoOrients) {
                stage.removeEventListener(StageOrientationEvent.ORIENTATION_CHANGING, orientationChanging);
                stage.addEventListener(StageOrientationEvent.ORIENTATION_CHANGING, orientationChanging, false, 100, true);
            }
        }

        private function orientationChanging(event:StageOrientationEvent):void {
            event.stopImmediatePropagation();
            if (event.afterOrientation == StageOrientation.ROTATED_LEFT  || event.afterOrientation == StageOrientation.ROTATED_RIGHT) {
                event.preventDefault(); 
            }   
        }

        protected function handleButtons(event:KeyboardEvent):void
        {
            if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.HOME) {
                // Handle Home button.
            }
            else if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.BACK) {
                // Hanlde back button.
                removeEverything();
            }
        }

    ]]>
</fx:Script>
<fx:Declarations>
    <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
</fx:Declarations>
</s:View>
```

Compiler arguments

```
-locale en_US
-swf-version=13 
-target-player=11.0
-define CONFIG::LOGGING false 
-define CONFIG::FLASH_10_1 true
```

*Added* Updated to code to have a StageVideoEvent listener and simplified to one view (also to know the renderMode is set to direct)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" title="video" backgroundAlpha="0" creationComplete="init(event)" >
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.core.UIComponent;

        protected var videoPath:String = new String("video.mp4"); 
        private var videoWidth:Number = 1280;
        private var videoHeight:Number = 680; 

        private var stageVideoAvail:Boolean;
        private var sv:StageVideo;

        private function init(e:Event):void {
            trace("ran one");
            onAddedToStage(); 
        }

        private function onAddedToStage():void {
            trace('test');
            stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
            stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT; 


               stage.addEventListener(StageVideoAvailabilityEvent.STAGE_VIDEO_AVAILABILITY, onStageVideoAvailability);

        }

        private function onStageVideoAvailability( e : StageVideoAvailabilityEvent ) : void
        {
            if (e.availability == StageVideoAvailability.AVAILABLE){
                stageVideoAvail = true;
                initVideo();
            } else {
                stageVideoAvail = false;
            }
        }

        private function initVideo():void
        {
            var obj:Object = new Object();
            var nc:NetConnection = new NetConnection();
            nc.connect(null);
            var ns:NetStream = new NetStream(nc);
            ns.client = obj;

            if(stageVideoAvail)
            {
                sv = stage.stageVideos[0];
                sv.addEventListener(StageVideoEvent.RENDER_STATE, onRender);
                sv.attachNetStream(ns);
                trace('available');
            }
            else
            {
                var vid:Video = new Video(videoWidth, 768);
                addChild(vid);
                vid.attachNetStream(ns);
                trace('not');
            }

            ns.play( videoPath );
        }

        private function onRender(e:StageVideoEvent):void
        {
            sv.viewPort = new Rectangle(0, 0, videoWidth, 768);
        }

        public function onMetaData(e:Object):void
        {

        }

        public function onXMPData(e:Object):void
        {

        }

    ]]>
</fx:Script>
<fx:Declarations>
    <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
</fx:Declarations>
</s:View>
```

The only other view in this application just has a button with navigator.pushView(Copyofvideo,null,null); and when ever the button is clicked the screen flickers and then it video plays.

Comment: were you able to solve the flickering and black screen?

Answer (score 0):

One possible reason for the flicker is that you don't listen for [`StageVideo`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/beta/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/StageVideo.html) availability before you call `_ns.play()`. By listening to [`StageVideoAvailabilityEvent.STAGE_VIDEO_AVAILABILITY`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/beta/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/StageVideoAvailabilityEvent.html), you can manage gaining and losing the `StageVideo`.

Instead of

```
private function onAddedToStage(e:Event):void
{ 
    ...
    _sv = stage.stageVideos[0]; 
    _sv.viewPort = new Rectangle(0, 42, videoWidth , videoHeight ); 
    _sv.attachNetStream(_ns); 

    playVideo(); 
}
```

do this

```
    private function onAddedToStage(e:Event):void
    {
        stage.addEventListener( StageVideoAvailabilityEvent.STAGE_VIDEO_AVAILABILITY, onStageVideoAvailability );
    }

    private function onStageVideoAvailability( event : StageVideoAvailabilityEvent ) : void
    {
        var available : Boolean = (event.availability == StageVideoAvailability.AVAILABLE);
        ...

        if ( available )
        {
            addStageVideo();
        }
        else
        {
            //implement an alternative e.g. addRegularVideo();
        }

        playVideo();
    }
```

Adobe Developer Connection discusses how to listen for StageVideo availability in this tutorial:

[Getting started with stage video](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/stage_video.html)

and this tutorial provides some more code samples:

[Creating a StageVideo Test in FDT with Flex 4.5 and FlashPlayer 10.2](http://blog.patricktresp.de/2011/04/creating-a-stagevideo-test-in-fdt-with-flex-4-5-and-flashplayer-10-2/)

Comment: It seems to be still flickering. I added a event Listener for  stageVideoAvailability and tried to simplify it down to one view. The new code is at the bottom of the post under added. Should just be able to copy the view and the Compiler arguments and set renderMode to direct and add a video and see it. thank for you help by the way!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to change the render mode? I had problems with Stage Video when it was in Direct mode. Changing it to CPU seemed to fix problems with StageVideo that I had.